# Objective C - How can I create an interface?

Tags: objective-c, interface

I need to be able to create an interface like you create in C# to enforce a group of classes to implement certain methods.
Is this possible in objective c?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can create a protocol. it would look something like this:
in MyProtocol.h:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
-(void)myMethod;
-(void)myMethod2;
@end
```

in MyClass.h

```
#import "MyProtocol.h"
@interface MyClass : NSObject<MyProtocol>
@end
```

If you want to receive objects of a given protocol, you can do so like this:

```
id<MyProtocol> var;
```

or

```
NSObject<MyProtocol> *var;
```

more info [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocProtocols.html)

Answer (score 8):

You declare a "protocol" (Objective-C's interfaces) using

```
@protocol MyProtocol <BaseProtocol1,...,BaseProtocolN>
//methods and properties
@end
```

where `<BaseProtocol>` is optional and indicates that `MyProtocol` "inherits" `BaseProtocol`'s interface. The `NSObject` protocol is useful in this context because it allows you to use

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
//...
@end
```

to indicate (when appropriate) that conforming instances of `MyProtocol` have the standard `NSObject` methods as well (e.g. `-retain/-release`, etc.).

You then declare that a class "conforms" to a protocol:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyProtocol,...,OtherProtocols>
{}

@end
```

And you can test whether an instance conforms to a protocol:

```
id myInstance = ...; //some object instance

if([myInstance conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)]) {
  // myInstance conforms to MyProtocol
}
```

You can further silence compiler warnings by declaring that a variable holds instances that conform to a protocol (note that Objective-C's dynamic nature prevents the compiler from verifying that contract and you can still get runtime errors by assigning a non-conforming instance to the variable):

```
id<MyProtocol> o;
```

In this case, the compiler will complain if you send `[o retain]` without `MyProtocol` conforming to the `NSObject` protocol. You can silence these warnings by declaring `MyProtocol` as conforming to `NSObject` as described above or by delcaring `o` as

```
NSObject<MyProtocol> o;
```

Since `NSObject` is not the only root object in Cocoa (i.e. `NSProxy` does not inherit from `NSObject`), it's not necessarily true that all instances conforming to `MyProtocol` also conform to `NSObject`. If you know that they do, you can declare `MyProtocol` as conforming to `NSObject`.

Answer (score 2):

In the Objective-C world, interfaces are called "Protocols"

According to Apple,

```
Protocols declare methods that can be implemented by any class. Protocols are useful in at least three situations:

To declare methods that others are expected to implement
To declare the interface to an object while concealing its class
To capture similarities among classes that are not hierarchically related
```

So, to declare a protocol you can:

```
@protocol SomeClassProtocol
- (void) do:(int) number something:(id) sender;
- (void) somethingElse;
@end
```

To implement a protocol , you do:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <Protocol1, Protocol2, ..., ProtocolN>
@end
```

Check out [this link](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocProtocols.html) for the official documentation.

Comment: I think you mean *In the Objective-C world, interfaces are called "protocols"*.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are called protocols in Objective C

If you go to add a class to your project you will have an option to create it as protocol and you will end up with something like:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
-(void) DoSomething;
@end
```